# Increment a progress bar with button on visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to increment a progress bar 1% every time the i click a button and a radio button is check  it...? How can i make that.. im learning Visual Basic.. Thanks!

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    ProgressBar1.Increment(+1)


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then


    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: this is something you should google before asking.  there are `About 19,200 results` for timer, progress bar, vb.net on this site alone.  msdn also has some pretty good resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the timer for this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
    dim x as integer= ProgressBar1.value
    x += 1
    ProgressBar1.value = x

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something a lot simpler.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
End Sub
```

`PerformStep` moves the bar up one increment. The step in based upon your increment. To change it, change the `Step` in the properties. It is 10 by default. For more goodies go to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) for all progress bar fun.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = 100 '1000 is 1 sec
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    ProgressBar1.Increment(+1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using the timer? You do not need to.

Comment: Because I used his code. I don't know what the rest of his goal is. And for myself I made a custom ProgressBar with a timer to get percent in the bar without flickering. For me it work perfect like this.